# Junit TemporaryFolder: Folder path not as expected

Tags: junit

I am trying to use junit's TemporaryFolder feature.

In my setup, I create a folder hierarchy inside TemporaryFolder:

```
File testPath = temporaryFolder.newFolder("test03");
String dataPath = Paths.get(testPath.getAbsolutePath(), "data").toString();
String level1Folder = dataPath + "/folder1";
String level2Folder = level1Folder + "/folder2";
```

Following folder hierarchy is generated:

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\junit4670928837094140936\test03\data
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\junit4670928837094140936\test03\data/folder1
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\junit4670928837094140936\test03\data/folder1/folder2
```

I use these paths to mock an object's funtion. I want it to return certain values when object's function is called with above paths.

When test runs, I see that paths are as:

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\junit4670928837094140936\test03\data
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\junit4670928837094140936\test03\data/folder1
     C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\junit4670928837094140936\test03\data\folder1/folder2
```

First 2 paths are correct, and so mock works as expected. But third path is slightly different(direction of slash differs) from what I mocked, thus causing wrong value to return.

What can be the reason for this path variation?